# Finding a set with probability satisfying an inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intuition

**I am requesting a hint, not necessarily a complete solution. The intuition behind this solution is more important than the solution itself.**

Let's say I have a sample space $\Omega$ with $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) = 0$ for every singleton.

I have two disjoint sets $A, B \subset \Omega$ with $0 < \mathbb{P}(A) = k < \dfrac{1}{3}$ and $\mathbb{P}(B) > \dfrac{2}{3}-k$.

Is there a way I can construct a set $C \subset \Omega$, based on $A$, $B$, and $\Omega$ (using set operations), so that $\mathbb{P}(C) \in \left[\dfrac{1}{3}, \dfrac{2}{3} \right]$?

I have tried messing with unions, as well as complements of $A$ and $B$ relative to $\Omega$ to no avail. One thing I can say is that $\mathbb{P}(B) > \dfrac{1}{3}$.

Comment: It looks like $A\cup B=\Omega$ or at least $P(A\cup B)=1$.  That is unless you meant $P(A)\lt k=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is flawed.

Let $A,B$ be disjoint uncountable sets and let $\Omega=A\cup B$.

Let the event space $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of sets of the form $S\cup T$ where

- $S\subseteq A$ and one of the sets $S,A{\setminus}S$ is countable.$\\[4pt]$

  $T\subseteq B$ and one of the sets $T,B{\setminus}T$ is countable.

Let the probability function $P$ on $\mathcal{F}$ be such that

- $P(A)={\large{\frac{1}{6}}}$.$\\[6pt]$

  $P(B)={\large{\frac{5}{6}}}$.$\\[6pt]$

  $P(X)=0$ if $X\in\mathcal{F}$ and $X$ is countable.

It follows that

- All cocountable subsets of $A$ have probability ${\large{\frac{1}{6}}}$.$\\[6pt]$

  All cocountable subsets of $B$ have probability ${\large{\frac{5}{6}}}$.$\\[6pt]$

  $P(X)\in\{0,{\large{\frac{1}{6}}},{\large{\frac{5}{6}}},1\}\;$for all $X\in\mathcal{F}$.

Then the specified conditions on $A,B$ are satisfied, but there does not exist an event $C\in\mathcal{F}$ such that ${\large{\frac{1}{3}}}\le P(C)\le{\large{\frac{2}{3}}}$.

Comment: Thank you for answering the problem. It turns out that I need to add an additional condition that I didn't realize would be relevant. I've edited the post.

Comment: @Clarinetist: Taking your edit into account, I've revised my answer;